# Programmable UI Control segue

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am implementing facebook login using the programmably created facebook login button. Now after sucessfully logining in, I want to open another view. My problem is since I cannot see the programmably created button in the storyboard, I am not able to control -drag to create a segue to open another view. How can I fire a segue without control-draging. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the click of the button by adding a target to your button:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonClicked"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And create a function named buttonClicked like this:

```
func buttonClicked(){
    var nextView:[Your view class name] = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("[id of your view]") as [Your view class name]

    self.presentViewController(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can set the id of your viewController by selecting your new view in the storyBoard and then going in the identity inspector and setting the storyBoard id to what you want

Comment: @ Clement, thanks for your help. I am new to iOS app development and I don't know where to put the above codes.

Comment: `button.addTarget`: in your viewDidLoad function
`buttonClicked`: bottom of your class

Comment: But first you need to ctrl-drag at the top of your button to your class to create a variable for your button named button